# inject repository into unit of work

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Please see the code below:

```
public IUnitOfWork<PersonEntities> Create(IRepository<PersonDTO> repository)
        {
            var context = new PersonEntities();
            var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context);
            repository._dbContext = context;
            return unitOfWork;
        }
```

This is part of a factory class whose responsibility is to create a Unit of Work.  Notice that a repository is passed into the factory and the factory class populates the repositories _dbContext pproperty?

This does not look right to me i.e. a class (factory) is modifying the state (_dbcontext property) of another class (repository).  Is this "wrong"?

Comment: Without knowing the details, what I see if a method that creates a context, creates a unit of work, modifies a repository and returns the unit of work. This seems like three responsibilities. So I'd say it looks wrong too.

Comment: David Arno, I see two responsibilities i.e. create a unit of work and modify the repository.  Would returning the unit of work not be part of the function that creates the unit of work? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you are saying.  Creating and returning breaks the CQRS principle.   Is that right? Thanks.

Comment: Changing incoming parameters in a method called `Create` seems mightily confusing. I'd probably leave the method as it is, but rename it to something like `ChangeRepositoryContext`.

Comment: @amon, but it creates and returns a Unit of Work?

Comment: @David Arno, do you agree with my last comment? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're using Entity Framework ("PersonEntities").  Note that Entity Framework *already implements a "Unit of Work" strategy.* See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) for an example.